# Every nondecreasing function on [0,1] is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

Prove:Every nondecreasing function on $[0,1]$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions.

I know every nondecreasing function can only have at most countable discontinuous point, but still cannot construct such a sequence of continuous functions.

Comment: @hermes No, it's pointwise everywhere not almost everywhere .

Comment: Take a look at $x \mapsto \frac{x}{|x|+n^{-1}}$ to get an idea.}

Comment: @ MooS , you want to move the discontinuous points?

Comment: No, I just gave you an idea how to pointwise converge to one single jump". Should be not that hard to make this work for countable many "jumps".

Comment: @ MooS, ok, I will think abut this.

Comment: @MooS: Can you give more hint on how to make use of your function? If the discontinuous point is dense, I don't see how one can glue your function to the original one....